# Pyqt how to connect a func to ALL Qpushbutton

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I have a func want to connect all Qpushbutton, but I don't know how to set it.

Now I only to use **dict** list all attr, and filter Qpushbutton, but I don't know how to setting, connect.

That is my code:

```
 def test_fn(self):
     item_dict = self.__dict__
     for key in item_dict:
         attr = item_dict[key]
         if type(attr) is QPushButton:
             print key
             ###that is i don't know how to set
             # setattr(self,key,pyqtBoundSignal.connect(self.showx))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should be able to use connect directly:

```
def test_fn(self):
    item_dict = self.__dict__
    for key in item_dict:
        attr = item_dict[key]
        if isinstance(attr, QPushButton):  # isinstance will also detect subclasses, but you might not need it
            print key
            attr.clicked.connect(self.showx)
```

Comment: Good! 
I try connect a clicked event.
so i use attr.clicked.connect(self.showx)

it's work!

Comment: Yes, sorry, mistake from my part. I will update the answer